# how to add shapes using java code to a xml layout?

Tags: android

As per my requirement I need to add tow rectangles in a existing xml layout through java code. I can create the rectangle shapes using ondraw method, but using intents in fresh layout. I need to display that shapes in existing layout. If any one faces this experience, please help me to create shapes in a xml. Any responce would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the rectangles have a predefined place and size it it only a question of changing the visibility at runtime.

Give the rectangle the attribute android:visibility="gone" in the xml, and from the code use the setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) on the reference to the widget when you want to show it. In this way you may hide it again when no longer needed.

If this answer does not help you please specify more details and I may be able to help you better.

BR,
Vanja